how to dump svn repository when server files were lost
My svn server computer had a power outage, and when I restarted my svn server, I find some files in directory of revs were lost, and now my svn dump sript can't execute. The error is 'svnadmin: E160006: No such revision 1002'
svnadmin dump -q --deltas --incremental /home/repository/pandr/  -r 1003 > /tmp/repos_20240605.dmp

Here is my svn server directory of revs; you'll notice that the 1002 file is missing.
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 14946 Jul  4 02:56 1000
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  1962 Jul  4 03:06 1001
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  1423 Jul  4 03:11 1003

I'm trying to find a dump configuration to skip the missing file. However it seems like there is no resolution, as I don't have a backup of these files. Who can tell me how to restore svn?

Without any additional information, all we can really tell you is that if you have lost data, it's lost.

we have many higher version files，such as 1003、1004、1005、...、4005，this higher version files can‘t recover? is there one way to build 1002 file? such as  try to use svnkit to generate 1002 file

Where would the synthesized data come from? If you don't have a backup, that revision is lost. As a workaround, you can copy 1001 to 1002 but I really don't see what you would accomplish by doing that.

I just loss 1022 revision file, but 1003、1004、1005、...、4005 still exists, I try copy 1001 to 1002, but revison file will be checked, this file content check fail, is there one way to dump revision 1003 or higher revision?
